# Not able to return ActionResult from a controller which calls async method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I am working on a sample app to query an api and I am trying to move the generic piece into QueryAsync which queries and returns Task. This function will be called from a controller action GetData which can returns Task too. Here, I am awaiting while retrieving the result from QueryAsync. I feel it is not required as QueryAsync is not returning an awaitable object. But then if I don't, i will not be able to return ActionResult from GetData controller. Is my thinking and implementation here correct? Sorry, but I am new to using Async with MVC.

```
private async Task<ActionResult> QueryAsync<T>(string url)
{
    Task<string> response_task = HttpClientService.HttpClientService.GetRequest(url);
    IEnumerable<T> model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(await response_task);
    return View(model);
}

//
// GET: 
public async Task<ActionResult> GetData()
{
    string _address = "https://someurl";
    return await QueryAsync<ClassType>(_address);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an awaitable `Task` from `QueryAsync`, which is a `Task` that "asynchronously" runs `GetRequest`, then synchronously deserializes the result and returns an `ActionResult`. Think of those operations as a whole, squeezed into an awaitable Task.

From async/await API perspective, your implementation  is correct. Your implementation is equivalent to the following (ignoring generic method):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetData()
{
    var url = "https://someurl";
    var response = await HttpClientService.HttpClientService.GetRequest(url);
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ClassType>>(response);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can change it like that, but I do need the generic method in place, so I can pass any class type. My question is that is there a way I can return ActionResult from GetData method and still be async throughout, as anyways I am not 'returning' awaitable data but only 'View(model)'. I hope you are understanding my concern here.

Comment: You are returning an awaitable data, because `View(model)` depends on `model`, `model` depends on deserialize operation which then depends on asynchronous result of `GetRequest`. Without the result of `GetRequest`, there is no `model` thus there is no `ActionResult` to return.

Comment: See, `GetData` has to wait for `View(model)` to be constructed. It is awaitable. I don't know how else I can explain this, you need some insight on asynchronous operations in general aside from await/async API. e.g. see async stuff in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, I understood from your previous comment, and it does make much more sense now. Thanks!